# Icon Launcher Creating Icons Inconstantly Switching Between Round and Square

Tags: android, android-studio, icons

I have three different applications, all of which I am using the same style to create icons. Right-click *mipmap* > *New* > *Image Asset*

Using these settings:

[image]

But two icons have shrunk to the center of a round icon (blue and green) and one has the full icon as a square (Red) Which is  I want.

[image]

When I look in Finder at the icons themselves they look normal.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Read the [Adaptive Icons Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive.html). If you target 26+, you need to provide adaptive launcher icons or the launcher will place your default icon fully within the mask of the launcher icon background. Notice that Gmail also has the white circle around its icon in your screenshot.

Comment: Ok I'll check it out. But that doesn't explain why 1 of the icons isn't the same.

Comment: is the red square targeting < 26?